# How to log a shell script output within the script

Tags: shell, ksh, output-redirect

I have a ksh93 script (but the question is not ksh related).

Currently, I run my script with something like :

```
./script 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

I'm wondering what should I had in my script to get exactly the same result (screen output and a logfile containing both STDOUT and STDERR output).
Of course, I want to avoid adding '| tee logfile' for each echo/print I do.

Of course, a way to do that could be to wrap my script in another one that simply run './script 2>&1 | tee logfile' but I was wondering if this could be done inside the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common technique that is somewhat fragile is:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -z "$NOEXEC" && { NOEXEC=1 exec "$0" "$@" 2>&1 | tee logfile; exit; }
...
```

This will discard the return value and exit with the value returned by `tee`.  This may or may not be an issue, and may be the desired behavior.

Comment: Could you comment on the necessity of the `exit`? It seems that will make the script always exit with status 0, regardless of the exit status of `tee`.

Comment: Never mind, `exit` is needed to prevent the script from running twice. But perhaps `exit $?` is necessary.

Comment: `exit` with no arguments is the same as `exit $?`

Comment: *sigh* My mistake; I thought it defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 4):

If the current contents of your script is:

```
command1 arg1
command2 arg2
```

You can wrap that lot (inside the script) like this:

```
{
command1 arg1
command2 arg2
} 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

The `{` to `}` code is now a unit of I/O redirection within the script; the I/O redirection at the end applies to all the enclosed commands.  It does not create a subshell; any variables set in the commands are available to the script after the I/O redirection.

The `{` and `}` are slightly peculiar syntactically; in particular, `}` must be preceded by a semicolon or newline.

Comment: your solution seems more "clean" than william's one, but used with my script, it returns without doing all the job. weird, don't know why, and don't have the time to investigate for the moment. I have lot of command run via ssh on distant machines which are not executed within bracket (using ksh93).

Comment: Odd — I'm not sure why that would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just place your code in a function and call it.

```
your_func(){
#your code
}
your_func $@ 2>&1 | tee logfile
```